# Can't fetch data in Samsung TV (tizen app)

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, samsung

I am making a app for Samsung TV with Tizen studio. I am fetching data from API, the endpoint is simple a GET endpoint. The same code works in other browsers or if I open the Html file in the browser the API succeeded and got response. But in the Samsung TV, it is getting empty response.
Here is the code that I am using,

```bash
const apiUrl = 'https://example.com/apiGetEndpoint';

// Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Configure the GET request
xhr.open('GET', apiUrl, true);


    // Set up a callback function to handle the response
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      // Check if the request is complete
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        // Check if the response status is OK (status code 200)
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // Parse the response as JSON
//        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("XHR: ", xhr);
            var response = xhr.responseText;
          // Handle the response data
          console.log("Response: ", response);
        } else {
          // Handle the error (e.g., display an error message)
          console.error('Request failed with status:', xhr.status);
        }
      }
    };

// Send the GET request
xhr.send();
```

I am really stucked on that, if you know the solution please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, have you added required privileges for your webapp? https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/understanding-tizen-programming/security-and-api-privileges?langredirect=1

Comment: http://tizen.org/privilege/internet should be added for internet access

Comment: No, I've not added that internet privilege. But now I have added and it's not working.
No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/tutorials/web-runtime/#content-security-policy). I suppose that you are missing content-security-policy entry in your application config.xml file.

Just add your url(https://example.com/apiGetEndpoint) to config to allow it to be a connect-src.

```
<tizen:content-security-policy>default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://example.com/apiGetEndpoint; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';</tizen:content-security-policy>
```

If above will not solve your problem, you can also check [this page](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/w3c/security/cors/) for more possible problem causes.

Comment: Work like champ.
there is a very small community of samsung developers, so I've made a slack for samsung developers to solve each other's problem. If you can join here it would be great to have you there [slack](https://join.slack.com/t/samsungdevelopers/shared_invite/zt-23msostpj-5M93WobGvS7SlaRYPiCPDw)